# OrientDB Import from a CSV file to a Graph - ETL

Tags: csv, graph, import, orientdb

This CSV has already created an ETL and imported it into OrientDB:

**`userlist.csv`:**

```
ID,NAME
1,SATOSHI
2,TONA
3,MIKI
4,YUJI
5,OTA
```

However, I do not know how to make an ETL that imports this CSV that makes an edge.

**`relation.csv`:**

```
FROM_ID,TO_ID,WEIGHT
1,2,4
1,3,4
1,5,3
2,5,3
2,3,5
...
```

`FROM_ID` and `TO_ID` indicate the `ID` of `userlist.csv`. `WEIGHT` is optional.

Please teach me how to write ETL correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    {
  "source" : {
    "file": { "path": "your_path/relation.csv" }
  },
  "extractor" : {
    "csv": {}
  },
   "transformers": [
        { "command": { "command": "CREATE EDGE E FROM (SELECT FROM userlist-class where id = ${input.FROM_ID}) TO (SELECT FROM userlist-class where id = ${input.TO_ID}) set weight=${input.WEIGHT}"} }
    ],
  "loader" : {
    "orientdb": {
      "dbURL": "plocal:your-path/databases/db-name",
      "dbUser": "your-user",
      "dbPassword": "your-pwd",
      "serverUser": "your-server-user",
      "serverPassword": "your-server-pwd",
      "dbType": "graph",
      "classes": [{"name": "userlist-class-name", "extends":"V"}]
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
{
  "source" : {
    "file": { "path": "C:/Users/Sorint.Lab/Desktop/Orient/Community/orientdb-community-2.2.24/config/relation.csv" }
  },
  "extractor" : {
    "csv": {}
  },
   "transformers": [
        { "command": { "command": "CREATE EDGE USER_RELATION_FRIEND FROM (SELECT FROM userList where id = ${input.FROM_ID}) TO (SELECT FROM userList where id = ${input.TO_ID}) set weight=${input.WEIGHT}"} }
    ],
  "loader" : {
    "orientdb": {
      "dbURL": "plocal:C:/Users/Sorint.Lab/Desktop/Orient/Community/orientdb-community-2.2.24/databases/stack45504136",
      "dbUser": "admin",
      "dbPassword": "admin",
      "serverUser": "root",
      "serverPassword": "root",
      "dbType": "graph",
      "classes": [
            {"name": "userList", "extends":"V"},
            {"name": "USER_RELATION_FRIEND", "extends":"E"}
            ]
    }
  }
}
```

Hope it helps

Regards

Comment: I tried it but received the following error.
**
 ERROR exception=Error parsing query:
CREATE EDGE USER_RELATION_FRIEND FROM (SELECT FROM USER_INFO WHERE ID = ) TO (SELECT FROM USER_INFO WHERE ID = 2) SET weight=
     ^
Encountered " <CREATE> "CREATE "" at line 1, column 1.
**


Is there anything else you can do?

Comment: No, it does not exist. I thought about making it with this ETL.

Comment: Thank you update your answer.I tried that, but again I got the same error. Is "CREATE" usable in this ETL?